# Caching MongoDB connections in Django

Tags: django, caching, mongodb, database-connection

I'm using the standard (as opposed to NonRel) version of Django connected to PostgreSQL on top of Apache + mod_wsgi. 
This setup also connects to MongoDB (some data is saved externally). Right now I have to create a new MongoDB connection for each Django request, and pass it along throughout the call stack to all functions that require access to MongoDB. Is there a way to cache connections between requests?

**Edit**

At the risk of blasphemy, would a global variable work in this case?

Comment: To clarify, I am presuming that you mean caching on the django side, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Want to avoid creating a new connection in Django upon every request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways explaining how pymongo can work (or fail) with mod_wsgi, suggested here: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/faq.html?highlight=wsgi#does-pymongo-work-with-mod-wsgi

In addition you can use some kind of pooling solution, like described here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Notes+on+Pooling+for+Mongo+Drivers

One project that I know already to have pooling is [MongoEngine](http://mongoengine.org/), its a very simple ORM that uses pymongo behind the scenes. You might want to look into it together with the pymongo faq solutions above.

Comment: MongoEngine isn't an option because A) it's not very stable as far as I understand, and B) it requires me to abandon the existing SQL backend. I need a hybrid solution.

Comment: MongoEngine is quite stable, from what I experienced. And it does not require you to abandon anything, unless you want to.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the known issue with C extensions. Although it doesn't really have to do with caching connections. Pooling, too, is an option, but only if it's really possible to reuse connections across requests, which is still not clear to me.

Comment: Also, if you dont want to use MongoEngine ORM layer - then you can run plain pymongo commands via its connection pool.

Comment: As the FAQ explains, you can force all wsgi to run in the same application group, or run mod_wsgi in daemon mode (which has the same connection cached).

Comment: If MongoEngine doesn't replace the database backend then you still have to call connect somewhere yourself, no? I'll definitely look into the daemon mode option though. Thanks.

Comment: You put a mongoengine.connect() at the top of your settings.py or something, and from there on all calls done via mongoengine go through the pool. So yes, it is a global variable of a sort. You don't have to use MongoEngine, its open source - you can cut out just the pool/connection stuff.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12554/discussion-between-gigantt-com-and-evgeny)

Answer (score 3):

You can instantiate MongoDB connection somewhere and import it as opposed to calling `pymongo.connection.Connection()` every time you need it. Or you can create a Singleton to do this. Something like this in `settings.py`.

```
class ConnectionSingleton(object):
    """Represents a MongoDB connection"""
    conn=None
    def __new__(cls,*args,**kwds):
        if cls.conn is None:
            cls.conn=pymongo.connection.Connection()
        return cls.conn
```

Wouldn't this solve your problem?

Comment: Since pymongo claims that it's thread safe and does connection pooling inside its Connection class at this point it seems that I can just declare the connection inside the view, or indeed in the settings file, and it will "just work", even when accessed by multiple threads under wsgi. Pymongo's example project seems to do just this: https://github.com/mdirolf/DjanMon/blob/master/status/views.py