# Pymongo: returning a MongoClient if already exists

Tags: python, django, mongodb, pymongo

I'm using `pymongo` in a Django command that is run multiple times. What I'm trying to do is sharing a connection instance at the project level, so in `settings.py` I have something like:

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://mongo:27017/')
```

and in the command I have:

```
from django.conf import settings
# then do something w/ setting.client...
```

The problem w/ this approach is that each time I run my Django command, settings are imported and AFAIK a new mongo connection is opened.

Is there any better strategy for returning an existing connection without opening up a new one from scratch?

Comment: Did you try to look at it :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992718/caching-mongodb-connections-in-django ??

Comment: Just checked. The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11034084/4820341) suggests to use tools such ad MongoEngine to work project-wide with an ODM. 

However, I just need to run several queries (not related to any Django model) calling multiple times the same Django command and using the same shared `MongoClient`, without creating a new one for every run.

Comment: For future readers, this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25556034/4820341) may help